# ace editor findAll is not working. Need all Word with dif. Values in Array

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Good Morning (in some regions :) )

Trying to figure ist out since days, but still is not working. in this code i can find with my rows only exact where the Cursor is, the one Word in the Text. But i need to find all. The Text is EXW90= and an Value. the Values are different. I want to Port all values in an Array - still not working.
the variable "zeile" gives me all line numbers where is START and END - that works perfekt, but in this START and END I need to find ALL EXW90= value..
who can help?
D is not necessary (only as information).

```
function handle_PulsTeilwert(read){
function getText(tag, startpos, bwards, srange, wrap) {
    if (!wrap) wrap = false;
    var Range = require('ace/range').Range;
    var zeile = [];
    editor.findAll('needle',{
      backwards: bwards,
      wrap: wrap,
      caseSensitive: false,
      wholeWord: false,
      regExp: false,
      range: srange,
      start: new Range (startpos.row, startpos.column, startpos.row, startpos.column)
    });
    editor.$search.set({ needle: tag });
    zeile = editor.$search.find(editor.getSession());
    return zeile;
}
var Range = require('ace/range').Range;
for (var D=1; D<=4; D++) {
    var start = -1, end = -1;
    var cursor = editor.getCursorPosition();
    start = getText('(start_#D'+D.toString()+'_geom)', cursor, true, null);
    end = getText('(end_#D'+D.toString()+'_geom)', cursor, false, null);
    if (start !== null && end !== null)
        if (cursor.row < end.start.row && cursor.row > start.start.row) {
            end.start.row = cursor.row;
            break;
        }

}
if (start === null || end === null) return;
if (read){
    var sRange = new Range (start.start.row, 0, end.start.row, 0);
    var needle = /EXW90=[0-9]\b|EXW90=[1-9][0-9]\b|EXW90=[1-9][0-9][0-9]\b|EXW90=[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b|EXW90=[1-8][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b|EXW90=90000\b/;
    var teilPulsWert = getText(needle, cursor, true , sRange); //where is the last EXW90 value
    alert(teilPulsWert[0]); //in this var the first array value, in[1] the next and so on...
```

to get the real text with only the value i used

```
teilPulsWert.start.column++; 
newTeilPulsWert = editor.session.getTextRange(teilPulsWert).replace('EXW90=', '') ;
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have an Ideo to do it, it is working perfectly

with

```
    var contentINcnc = ace.edit("editor"); //read all content in editor
var getContentINcncData = (contentINcnc.getSession().getValue()).split('EXW90=') ; //find all EXW90 an write it in an Array
getContentINcncData[1] = parseFloat(getContentINcncData[1].match(/\d+\.?\d*/gi)[0]); //read out only the values, found in "EXW90=".
```

this runs perfectly. I have all values of EXW90 found in the editor here in my Array.

PERFECT for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:-

```
editor.findAll('needles',{
            wrap: true,
            caseSensitive: true, 
            wholeWord: true,
            regExp: false,
            // preventScroll: true // do not change selection
        })
```

var range = editor.getSelection().getAllRanges();

Range will then have the list of arrays of all the occurences.